# Scope down statement on WAFv2 using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf

I've created a managed rule group statement using Terraform and i'm now trying to add a scope down statement to it in order to exclude requests from a specific url. This can be done very easily on the AWS console however according to [Terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl#scope_down_statement) it appears that `scope_down_statement` can't be associated with `managed_rule_group_statement`.

Am I missing something? Here's is where i'm trying to add the scope_down_statement:

```
  resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "example" {
  name        = "waf-example"
  description = "Example of a managed rule"
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  rule {
    name     = "AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList"
    priority = 0

    override_action {
      none {}
    }

    statement {
      managed_rule_group_statement {
        name        = "AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList"
        vendor_name = "AWS"
      }
    }
```

Comment: "Here's is where i'm trying to add the scope_down_statement": where are you trying to add it? I don't see it in your code anywhere. Also, please provide the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. You need to upgrade the AWS provider version to 3.50. Please see the https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19407

Thanks